# What should our requirements on various "recommend me something" questions be?

Tags: discussion, questions

See also [Do we want resource recommendation questions?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2542/29), [Are software recommendation questions on topic?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/23/29) and to a lesser extent [When are software-recommendation questions on topic?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/563/29).

As pointed out elsewhere, we already [have tags that are meant to be about various "recommend me something" questions](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2542/29).

Several other sites have specific standards for what they consider to be acceptable recommendation questions. See for example those of [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/14091) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/1813).

Given that there is a fair consensus for us accepting questions on the form "please recommend me an X to do Y" (where X so far has primarily been software), we should have a set of standards for what makes such a question acceptable, and ideally what makes for a good answer to such a question. As far as I can tell, we have so far been rather non-specific in this regard.

**What should those standards be?**

*Please post separate answers discussing the questions and the answers respectively,* as the standards for each are likely to be different.

Answer (score 3):

## Questions should be focused on a particular aspect of the WB process

Avoid

- Can you recommend a book for worldbuilding?
- Which software should I get to build my world?

Prefer

- Which book do you recommend to help me getting the right relation between the main religion and the political power in an European Renaissance setting?
- Is there a software which can use fractal methods to help me draw the map of the continent?

Answer (score 2):

## Answers should be clear and specific, possibly adding link(s) to the resource in question

In case of a fixed resource (film, book, etc.) a small summary should be added, to give a chance to the OP to evaluate the relevance of the resource to her/him.

Avoid

- *In a book by Shakespeare, you'll find an example.*

  Problem: is the OP expected to read the complete work of Shakespeare to find an example which might not stretch more than a few pages?

Prefer

- *In Romeo & Juliet by Shakespeare ([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1505259568)/[Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1112)), you'll find some material about the organisation of families in early Italian renaissance. For example, we learn that [...].*